# With poetry is there a way to quickly check for changes in poetry.lock to run before every command?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, python-poetry

I'm new to poetry - not an excuse but rather to set the frame for this question :)

I'd like to have a small wrapper around `poetry run` which first checks if the associated virtual environment is up to date with `poetry.lock` and then (conditionally) run `poetry install` if needed.

For example if `Pipfile.lock` didn't change, `pipenv sync` terminates fast enough to just let it run before every invocation of `pipenv run`, while `poetry sync` takes more than 6 seconds for me just to realize nothing has to be done at all.

A naive approach demonstrating what I want to achieve would be to write a `Makefile` target defining a dependency from `poetry.lock` to `.venv/some_random_file` and `touch` this file together with running `poetry install` every time that file is not up to date with `poetry.lock`. But I don't want to pollute my project with a dependency to `make` just for this case of course.

So is there a way to let poetry do this check without additional tools?

Comment: I think: [`poetry install --sync`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install)

Comment: that takes about the same amount of time, unfortunately

Comment: Maybe you can work with the output of the dry run: `poetry install --sync --dry-run`